# Probability Question: Who's right, me or the book?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'll be giving some classes on probability theory later this year, and so I've been going through the textbook to check that I'm up to speed. I came across the following question:

**The discrete random variable $X$ has the cumulative distribution function $\mathrm{F}$ defined by
$$\mathrm{F}(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & & x=0 \\
\frac{(x+k)^2}{16} & & x=1,2,3 \\
1 & & x > 3 \end{array}\right.$$
Find the value of $k$.**

As far as I can tell, there isn't enough information to solve the problem. Using the fact that $\mathrm{F}(x) = \mathrm{P}(X\le x)$, and so $\mathrm{P}(X=x)=\mathrm{F}(x)-\mathrm{F}(x-1)$, I have obtained
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X=0) &=& 0 \\ \\
P(X=1) &=& \tfrac{1}{16}(1+k)^2 \\ \\
P(X=2) &=& \tfrac{1}{16}(3+2k) \\ \\
P(X=3) &=& \tfrac{1}{16}(5+2k) \\ \\
P(X=4) &=& \tfrac{1}{16}(1-k)(7+k) \\ \\
P(X \ge 5) &=& 0
\end{eqnarray*}$$

As far as I can tell, these satisfy $\mathrm{F}(x)=\mathrm{P}(X \le x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$, independently of $k$.

Since all probabilities must lies between $0$ and $1$, I imposed the conditions $0 \le \mathrm{P}(X=x) \le 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$. Solving these inequalities tells us that $-\frac{3}{2} \le k \le 1$.

The books says that $k=1$ is the answer, but I think that $k$ with $-\frac{3}{2} \le k \le 1$ are all valid answers.

**What have I missed?!**

Comment: By continuity from the right, $\Pr(X\le 3)=1$. The book is right. They were a bit sloppy about making clear that the cdf is defined everywhere.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Please post "answers" as answers. That way I can up-vote.

Comment: It's very simple: (i) A c.d.f. has to be right-continuous. Therefore, (ii) $F(3)=1$. Therefore, (iii) $(k+3)^2=16$.

Comment: @FlybyNight: Are you sure you copied the question faithfully? Instead of "defined by", the question should say "which satisfies". Because the so-called definition leaves the values of $F(x)$ unspecified for non-integral values in $(0,3)$. (The answer to the question is not affected by this, however.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know whether the book defines the cdf properly, as being defined for all real $x$.  If it does, then what we have is only a partial description of the cdf.
However, the description is sufficient to determine $k$.

A cdf is continuous from the right, so from $F(x)=1$ for $x\gt 3$ we can conclude that $F(3)=1$. The formula for $F(3)$ then shows that $(3+k)^2=16$.  That yields $k=1$ or $k=-7$.  However, $k=-7$ is impossible. For if $k=-7$ then $F(1)\gt 1$.

Comment: It just says that $\mathrm{F}(x) = \mathrm{P}(X\le x)$. Having said that, it makes reference to $\mathrm{F}(2.6)$ and says "$\mathrm{F}(2.6)$ means $\mathrm{P}(X\le 2.6)$ but $X$ doesn't take any values between $2$ and $3$ so $X \le 2.6$ is the same as $X \le 2$ and thus $\mathrm{F}(2.6) = \mathrm{F}(2)$."

Comment: Surely $F(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n p \{ k \}$? with $F$ being a right-continuous step function on non-integral values of the parameter?

Comment: From the fact that it discusses $F(2.6)$, one concludes it defines the cdf properly.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Not really; I have given you all that it says. That's a pretty lousy definition. If it were defined properly then I wouldn't be making this post! I'm still unsure that all of the probabilities listed in my OP don't meet the criteria of the question, and the book.

Comment: @FlybyNight I think right continuity is sufficient to weed out other values of $k$. No?

Comment: I don't see where continuity enters into this. The formula $F$ defines the cdf for values $0,1,2,3$. Since it is discrete, it seems reasonable to assume that $F$ is constant (and right-continuous) for values **other** than $0,1,2,3$? I would concur that $k \in [-1.5,1]$ will define a valid cdf. (again assuming that $F$ is extended to other values in the usual way).

Comment: I see the ambiguity (or my misinterpretation). The question is does $x>3$ above mean $(3,\infty)$ or $\{4,5,6,...\}$.

Comment: We are told explicitly that $F(x)=1$ for $x\gt 3$. I take that at face-value.

Comment: @copper.hat: I don't see any ambiguity here. $x > 3$ means $x \in (3,\infty)$ unless we are told otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I see. It was my misinterpretation. I interpreted it as $k>3$ and integral.

Comment: Well, the question was about a discrete random variable, so it is not entirely unreasonable.

Comment: @copper.hat: The c.d.f. of a discrete random variable is defined on the whole of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @TonyK: If you read the comments you will see my line of reasoning.

Comment: Yes, OK, if by "line of reasoning" you mean "thought processes" :-) But the question is not perfectly posed $-$ see my second comment to the OP.

Comment: @TonyK: I apologise for my snippy response earlier.